# What is the purpose of /usr/share/themes/Raleigh?

Tags: themes, gtk-2

Lubuntu 14.04.3 LTS fully updated.

What purpose does the Raleigh folder serve?

```
$ ls -AlR /usr/share/themes/Raleigh
/usr/share/themes/Raleigh:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 24 06:32 gtk-2.0

/usr/share/themes/Raleigh/gtk-2.0:
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 69 Sep 11 16:54 gtkrc
$
```

The contents of the `gtkrc` file are just this:

```
#
# This theme is the default theme if no other theme is selected.
#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This are the files for the "Raleigh" GTK theme, which is the default theme for GTK2. As it just uses the default look of GTK there isn't any real content there.

Comment: Also https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2014/06/13/a-new-default-theme-for-gtk/